# Missing return in global function expected to return 'String' message in a function

Tags: swift, xcode

I know this error is a common message and has already been the subject of many posts. However, as a pure beginner who just started days ago, I can't really understand the solution on other posts, and also haven't learned what Switch means. Thefore, that solution can't be used with me. Here's my block code getting the error :

```
func responseTo(question: String) -> String {
    let lowercasedQuestion = question.lowercased()

    if lowercasedQuestion.hasPrefix("hello") {
        if lowercasedQuestion.hasPrefix("Hello") {
            return "Why, hello there!"
        } else if lowercasedQuestion.hasPrefix("where") {
            if lowercasedQuestion.hasPrefix("Where") {
                return "To the North"
            } else {
                return "Where are the cookies?"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put the last else outside the first if since I read it could change the output and remove the error, but it didn't change anything. I tried to enter `return nil` on the last line, but had an error. What can I do? Any answer appreciated.

Comment: I've formatted your code; Do you see the problem(s)?

Comment: Can you see a path that would allow you to reach the end of the function without returning a String?

Comment: You need to return something in case your string does NOT `hasPrefix("hello")` or change your return type to `String?` and return `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `responseTo(String) -> String` function must return a String. You must consider this case, if the parameter (question) doesn't start with "hello", the function doesn't have any String to return.

```
let result: String = responseTo("asd") // error
```

As stated in the comments, there are several ways to solve this.
If your function must return a string, then consider returning a default value at the end. The return value can be an empty string (but whatever your default value is, make sure to handle it properly).

```
func responseTo(question: String) -> String {
let lowercasedQuestion = question.lowercased()
    if lowercasedQuestion.hasPrefix("hello") {
        //
    } else {
        return "" // this will be the default return value
    }
}
```

or

```
func responseTo(question: String) -> String {
let lowercasedQuestion = question.lowercased()
    if lowercasedQuestion.hasPrefix("hello") {
        //
    }
    return "" // this will also be the default return value
}
```

Another way is to return an Optional String (String?). The reason why `return nil` doesn't work for `responseTo(String) -> String` is because it must return a string. To be able to return a nil, you will have to change the declaration of your function to `responseTo(String) -> String?`.

```
func responseTo(question: String) -> String? { // the "?" after String notifies the compiler that this function can return a String or a nil
let lowercasedQuestion = question.lowercased()
    if lowercasedQuestion.hasPrefix("hello") {
        //
    }
    return nil
}
```

you can read more about function [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) and optional [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer ! I tried every solution simply by curiosity to see what would result. At first, I put, `else {
        return "" // this will be the default return value
    }` but still had the same message. I realized I sort of have to put it outside the if statement, with the word else starting at the same abscissa than other if and else for it not to display this error. Also, I didn't know that we could add a ? at the end of String when we declare the type of the function. By the way, I still had the same problem after the formatting @tkausl ! Thanks you for the answer.